# python count number of unique elements in csv column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, unique, counter

I'm trying to get the counts of unique items in a csv column using Python.

Sample CSV file (has no header):

```
AB,asd
AB,poi
AB,asd
BG,put
BG,asd
```

I've tried this so far.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

input_file = open('Results/1_sample.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')

data = defaultdict(list)
for row in csv_reader:
    data[row[0]].append(row[1])
for k, v in data.items():
    print k
    print Counter(v)
```

This gives output in this format:

```
AB
Counter({'asd': 2, 'poi': 1})
BG
Counter({'asd': 1, 'put': 1})
```

But I want my output to be like:

```
AB:2
BG:2
total_unique_count:3 #unique count of column[1], irrespective of the data in column[0]
```

Comment: It has two unique values in column[1], asd and poi. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Ok so you want to remove duplicates, not count actually unique values?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, remove duplicates and then get the count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the SeriesGroupby method [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
    0    1
0  AB  asd
1  AB  poi
2  AB  asd
3  BG  put
4  BG  asd

In [12]: g = df.groupby(0)

In [13]: g[1].nunique()
Out[13]:
0
AB    2
BG    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It looks promising, but I get `pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
KeyError: 0`. I'll try to fix that and update.

Comment: 0 and 1 are the column names in the above DataFrame, yours may be different? (This groups by column 0 and the counts the number of unique elements in column 1, for each group.)

Comment: They are the same for my data also.

Comment: @pam also to get the total number of groups use `len(df[1].unique())`. Ok, not sure why that is, you've been able to do that since forever, perhaps the columns names are strings `'0'`?

Comment: @pam the way to find out is to look at df.columns. :)

Comment: My bad. You're right. I forgot to give header = None and it was considering the first row to be header. It works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
data = (('AB', 'asd'),
    ('AB', 'poi'),
    ('AB', 'asd'),
    ('BG', 'put'),
    ('BG', 'asd'))
unique_items = set(data)
keys = [[entry[0] for entry in unique_items]]
for key in set(keys):
    print("Key '{}' appears {} unique times".format(key, keys.count(key)))
```

> Key 'BG' appears 2 unique times
>   Key 'AB' appears 2 unique times

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need AB count to be only 2, not 3 (since asd is repeated in column[1] for AB)

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for completely unique entries, and then count by the key?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my bad phrasing.