# Count number of occurrence in a column Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the number of occurrences for each input in the column Echantillon. For example:

```
Echantillon   Classe
1001            0
956             1
9658            2
1001            0
8566            2
956             1
```

How can this be done using Python?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634417/python-count-number-of-unique-elements-in-csv-column?rq=1

Comment: Please check [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. As a general rule, I would think that a questioner puts in at least twice as much time into solving the problem themselves as it takes to describe the problem here, and show their working.

Comment: @EdChum thanks, i see

Comment: Search for "python count dictionary"; that will give you the needed data structure.  From there, you should be able to turn your list into a dictionary of frequency counts in one line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly then you want total numbers by classes. If it so then you can do it by:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   Echantillon  Classe
0         1001       0
1          956       1
2         9658       2
3         1001       0
4         8566       2
5          956       1
```

then you can use groupby function:

```
In [10]: df.groupby(df['Classe']).sum()
Out[10]: 
        Echantillon
Classe             
0              2002
1              1912
2             18224
```